# Struggling with sort

Tags: bash, sorting

I want to sort an output but Im struggling with using sort command.
My search results have a period between date today and next 30 days.
Output example

```
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►11.01.2012♦
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►01.01.2012♦
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►11.12.2011♦
```

The variable I try to sort is

```bash
VAR="$(find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name 'filename' | xargs grep -o -m 1 "♦SOMETEXT►►..........♦" | )"sort -t '.' -k 3 -k 2 -k 1
```

With that code I get sorted by filename but I want to get echo from $VAR sorted like

```
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►11.12.2011♦
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►01.01.2012♦
filename:♦SOMETEXT►►11.01.2012♦
```

That's how I need the output
Youngest year then youngest month (relative to year) then youngest day.
Month is maybe the tricky part when period to display is between dec and jan.

```
sort -t '.' -k 3 -k 2 -k 1
```

What is the correct sort command?

Comment: To make it short: You want to sort data according to a timestamp - from older to newer, right?

Comment: Is the command line you are using inside to get VAR like that or did you make a typo ? Like that with bash you'll get a syntax or parsing error. Try including your `sort` command inside like `$(... | sort)`.

Comment: please use a [repro]

Comment: @user1934428 not exactly. Every file has a date as content like shown in my example.
I want to filter this date by find and grep, store it as variable and get the output as echo then. The date outputs from every file in that folder should get displayed sorted as described. So I dont mean the files timestamp but their content.

Comment: @Marius_Couet actually Im using this var to echo the outputs as a list but sorting is done based on filename (filenames are also numbered) and not based on the outputed dates. So overall the var does its job but with wrong sorting.
All I want is to display the files that have dates regarding the next 30 days from today so I know which files I will have to work with next what I actaully have but I would like to have the results echoed sorted like mentioned.

Comment: I didn't mean file time stamps. You have a text file, consisting of several logical fields. One of the field represents a point in time (a date in your case). You want to sort the lines of this file according to this specific field. Isnt it this in essence? Otherwise, extend your question by adding example data, which we can copy and paste and reproduce this problem.

Comment: @user1934428 my folder contains hundreds of files and in some of these files there is one line where this info ♦SOMETEXT►►11.12.2011♦ is provided.
I need these date occurences get sorted when echo displays this grep output.

Comment: @user1934428 to clearify a bit more. all lines with the date in all files are commented out per default. my script only activates the line if the date is within next 30 days. so im able to grep these lines to get displayed which files i have to handle next.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and not really one for `sort`.

Comment: One _can_ use `sort` for this. The usual approach is to generate a synthetic key (using awk to add a first column in YYYYMMDD format, say), sort on that key, then strip it back out. Mind, it's good form to use YYYYMMDD _all the time_; you don't get confusion between US and European date formats (MM.DD.YYYY vs DD.MM.YYYY) that way.

Comment: @diggidre: So why do you want to sort the data then?

Answer (score 0):

*IF I understand correctly*, you just need to know which records to process?

Here's a pass at it that shows selection logic.

```
$: cat input
filename-foo:♦SOMETEXTsdfklj►►11.01.2012♦
filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►07.07.2023♦
filename-barr:♦SOMETEXTuixdjkdjn,tf►►01.01.2012♦
filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►09.07.2023♦
filename-fubar:♦SOMETEXT0938672039875►►11.12.2011♦

$: cat tst
today=$(date +%s)           # todays epoch date in seconds.
tod=$(( today % 86400 ))    # time offset for a truncate to midnight
today=$(( today - tod ))    # beginning of the day
d30=2592000                 # 30 days of seconds
while read l
do d=${l##*►►}; d=${d%♦*};         # assumes no ►►'s behind the date
   rec=$(date -d${d//.//} +%s)     # get epoch seconds of the record
   delay=$(( rec - today ))        # take a difference
   if (( delay < 0 ))
   then echo "in the past: $l"
   elif (( delay < d30 ))
   then echo "due: $l"
   else echo "still pending: $l"
   fi
done<input

$: ./tst
in the past: filename-foo:♦SOMETEXTsdfklj►►11.01.2012♦
due: filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►07.07.2023♦
in the past: filename-barr:♦SOMETEXTuixdjkdjn,tf►►01.01.2012♦
still pending: filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►09.07.2023♦
in the past: filename-fubar:♦SOMETEXT0938672039875►►11.12.2011♦
```

If it really is important that they be sorted, I'd recommend something inspired by a Schwartzian Transform, in which case you might as well exit as soon as you've processed all the due records.
With the same input -

```
$: cat tst

today=$(date +%s)           # todays epoch date in seconds.
tod=$(( today % 86400 ))    # the time of day offset - You might want to truncate to midnight.
today=$(( today - tod ))    # beginning of the day
d30=2592000                 # 30 days of seconds
while read l
do d=${l##*►►}; d=${d%♦*};                        # assumes there are no ►►'s behind the date
   rec=$(date -d${d//.//} +%s)                    # get epoch seconds datestamp from the record
   delay=$(( rec - today ))
   if (( delay > 0 ))
   then if (( delay < d30 ))
        then echo "due: $l"
        else echo "Pending: $l"
        fi
   else echo "Done"
        exit
   fi
done < <( sed -E 'h; s/^.*►([.0-9]+)♦.*/\1/; G; s/\n/ /' input |
            sort -rn -t. -k3 -k1 -k2 )

$: ./tst
Pending: 09.07.2023 filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►09.07.2023♦
due: 07.07.2023 filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►07.07.2023♦
Done
```

That preprocessing:

```
sed -E 'h; s/^.*►([.0-9]+)♦.*/\1/; G; s/\n/ /'
```

`h` copies the record to the save space.
the 1st `s///` replaces the whole line with just the matched date.
`G` addends the save space into the pattern space with a newline between.
the 2nd `s///` replaces the newline with a space.
The output, with my input file:

```
$: sed -E 'h; s/^.*►([.0-9]+)♦.*/\1/; G; s/\n/ /' input
11.01.2012 filename-foo:♦SOMETEXTsdfklj►►11.01.2012♦
07.07.2023 filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►07.07.2023♦
01.01.2012 filename-barr:♦SOMETEXTuixdjkdjn,tf►►01.01.2012♦
09.07.2023 filename-tst:♦SOMETEXT►►09.07.2023♦
11.12.2011 filename-fubar:♦SOMETEXT0938672039875►►11.12.2011♦
```

I am *assuming* that the stupid US standard of Month/Day/Year, so I sorted accordingly -

```
        sort -rn -t. -k3 -k1 -k2
```

if those dates are d/m/y, change the key order back to what you had initially.

Comment: thx for your answer!
I think what I want isnt possible or I did not discribe it good enough.
My output is there and all infos I need are on the screen but I just want sort to get things in the right sequence oldest date top newest date bottom :)

Comment: If that works for you, please accept and/or upvote. ;)